# How to hide div, when user end typing on "inputs" and go to the next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="word1"><input type="text" class="Q"></input><input type="text" class="A"></input></div><br>
<div id="word2"><input type="text" class="Q"></input><input type="text" class="A"></input></div><br>
```

I want to do, that if user end typing something on the Q input and do the same on the A input, div which was recently used, fadeOut ;)

My javascript:

```
var nowWord = 1;
var focusOuts = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#word" + nowWord + " > .Q").focusout(divFocusOut());
   $("#word" + nowWord + " > .A").focusout(divFocusOut());

   function divFocusOut(){
       focusOuts++;
       if(focusOuts == 2){
          $("#word" + nowWord).fadeOut(1000);
          focusOuts = 0;
       }
    }
});
```

The problem is: div fadeOut by itself without any user's actions, just after site load.
What's wrong?

Comment: If you want to hide the div after user entering some input and moves on to another div then You can write your logic in onBlur event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/YxAuk/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Q,.A").blur(function(e){
        if($(this).val().length>0 && $(this).siblings("input").val().length>0){
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: One problem: after fade out I'm adding new inputs (when old fades out, new appears). This code works with these inputs which are already in html file, but no with this new. How can I fix it?

Comment: For dynamically added elements you should use `on` handler like this `$(document).on('blur',".Q,.A",function(e){}`

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#word" + nowWord + " > .Q").focusout(divFocusOut());
$("#word" + nowWord + " > .A").focusout(divFocusOut());
```

That does that without user action. If you set the css here without a fade, the problem is gone. Or just set the CSS at the outset without javascript.

Or put that in the function, if you want it to occur, but not on page load.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand :/ Can you place here example?