# How to say jQuery to do .blur() function in newly appended object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is connected with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015804/how-to-hide-div-when-user-end-typing-on-inputs-and-go-to-the-next-div)
This code hides div when user type data to inputs and focus on another div

```
$(".Q,.A").blur(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0 && $(this).siblings("input").val().length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000);
        getData("ajaxPHP/insertNewWords.php?q='" + $(this).siblings('input').val() + "'&a='" + $(this).val() + "'&zestawID="+zestawID, "console");
        $(".main").append("<div><input type='text' class='Q'></input><input type='text' class='A'></input></div><br>");
    }
});
```

And when user enter data, this div hides and script creates new div (so user can enter infinite amount of data).
The problem is: new created divs don't hide.

So what should I do, if I want to involve new created divs into "$(".Q,.A")"?

Comment: Create them as jquery objects instead of a string. Then apply a `.blur()` to them.

Comment: since dynamic better go with delegates like `$(".Q,.A").on('blur',function(e) `

Comment: @user1671639 there is no delegate here, btw as blur doesn't bubbles, you cannot use delegation with it, you have to use onfocusout event

Comment: @roasted Blur does bubble, as said here: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: @bennofs As for jq 1.4.2, blur event is mapped around onfocusout to allow delegation. But still, onblur event doesn't bubbles by default and so using onfocusout specially for delegation is more appropriate. I forgot about this mapping, thx you to remember me it :) Here you can see that onblur doesn't bubbles, unlike specified by DOC it is not only in IE, tested in chrome/FF: http://jsfiddle.net/6tnf7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (as I understand it), that you have a behaviour attached to a set of nodes on your page, and new nodes added to the page do not pick up this behaviour.

This is because of the way JQuery works. When you define a selector like $(".Q,.A") this selector evaluates to a set of known nodes on your page. The code that follows only applies to those found elements. This selector is never evaluated again, so any new nodes never get a chance to gain your desired behaviour.

The solution is to get JQuery to re-evaluate the selector every time the event occurs. So you need to listen for the event globally, then filter to only handle the elements that match your selector.

The correct way to do this is [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("blur", ".Q,.A", function(){ ... });
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/sAT6L/

[Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has some discussion on how it used to be done in each version of JQuery.

Note: You should be able to restrict the scope to something more local than $(document).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method on the parent container, because events "bubble" to the parent container. The on function also allows you to specify a selector to filter the children elements, which gets applied dynamically, so you can use your ".Q,.A" selector there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").on("blur", ".Q,.A", function(e){
        if($(this).val().length>0 && $(this).siblings("input").val().length>0){
            $(this).parent().fadeOut(1000);
            $("#container").append('<div><input type="text" class="Q"><input type="text" class="A"></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rK3HS/1/